# Format nomencl in table style

Tags: tables, formatting, longtable, nomenclature, booktabs

For my thesis I wwant to format the nomencl in the same style as the rest. Simply put this means I want the nomencl to appear as follows:

> ---
>
> **Symbol Quantity Unit**
>
> ---
>
> t Time s
>
> rest of the list
>
> ---

The three lines shown above are respectifily \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule from the booktabs package.

I checked the nomentbl package but here I do not get the horizontal lines as required. Presuamably my skills in LaTeX hacking are not adequit enough to tackle this problem.

This is an example of an units input line:

```
\nomenclature[ra ]{$t$}{Time}
```

This is what I tried to get the lines:

```
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\toprule}
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\bottomrule}
```

But this did not work out.

Hopefully one can put me in the right direction!

Comment: I recommend the package glossaries with the style `long`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The glossaries package is used for the glossaries already. 
For this reason, I should make this work with the nomencl package

Comment: In this case it is  much better to use glossaries instead of nomencl.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel
Again I appreciate your suggestion, however, using glossaries would introduces other problems as my glossaries should look different.
Using two different packages I can discriminate between the two of them.

I think it should be possible, I see this style frequently in books.

Comment: I understand your scepticism but you can handle more than one style with glossaries. Working with `nomecltbl` you must modify the file `nomentbl.ist`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea about how you have tweaked your `nomentbl.sty`. For my `nomentbl.sty` file, this is what I added to  `nomentbl.ist` file to get the desired effect.

```
preamble "\n\\begin{thenomenclature}\n%
\\begin{longtable}[l]%
{lp{\\textwidth*\\real{0.6}}c!{\\extracolsep{\\fill}}lll}\\toprule  %% <------ rule here
\\multicolumn{1}{l}{Symbol}&\\multicolumn{1}{c}{Quantity}& \\multicolumn{1}
{c}{Unit}\\\\ \n %% <------ header here
\\bottomrule %% <------ rule here
\\nopagebreak\\\\*[\\parskip]\n"
postamble "\\bottomrule %% <------ rule here
\n\\end{longtable}\n\n\\end{thenomenclature}\n" keyword
"\\nomenclatureentry"
```

This is how it looks. [image: Beginning of the list]. [image]

You may appropriately edit your `nomentbl.ist` to get this effect.

Comment: Thanks, did work,

However, can someone explain what exactly happens in the follow declatration:

`{lp{\\textwidth*\\real{0.6}}c!{\\extracolsep{\\fill}}lll}`

Comment: That is saying how the long table should be (i.e., the description of the columns). Remember \begin{tabular}{ccccl}?

Comment: Harish Kumer
Yes, that part I do recognise. However, I can't see why we need four l declarations in addition to the rest.
Probably something with the multicol part?

Comment: You mean `p{\\textwidth....\\fill}`?. It is for reserving space for the `Quantity`.

Comment: @HarishKumar this worked beautifully! One thing I can't manage to do: I got equation numbers (using the `refeq` option) as a 4th column - how do I get a column header for those? I tried adding a 4th `multicolumn` command, but this shifts the equation numbers below to the right (nearly out of the page). Can you help?

Comment: @Christoph: I will be glad to oblige :) Can you provide some MWE? How about a new question.

Comment: @Christoph: A blind shot as I don't have your setup. Use `{lp{\\textwidth*\\real{0.5}}c!{\\extracolsep{\\fill}}llll}\\toprule  %% <------ rule here
\\multicolumn{1}{l}{Symbol}&\\multicolumn{1}{c}{Quantity}& \\multicolumn{1}
{c}{Unit}& \\multicolumn{1}{c}{Eq. No.}\\\\ `

Comment: Thanks for your pointers. In fact, manipulating the longtable column setup is not necessary. I just figured it out, you have to add an empty multicolumn between Quantity and Eq. No., apparently there's an invisible column before the "eqref" column!
`\\multicolumn{1}{l}{Symbol}&\\multicolumn{1}{l}{Quantity}&\\multicolumn{1}{c}{Unit}&\\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\\multicolumn{1}{l}{Cf.~Eq.}\\\\%` works correctly!